# Service Bus for Windows Server - automatic deployment of certificates on the client

Tags: deployment, servicebus

On my project, we use Service Bus For Windows Server (Version 1.1). We use it on a local network.The minimal configuration is : one client uses the service bus and the core server uses also the Service Bus.

For the moment, we export the certificates on the clients manualy.  We follow the procedure written on this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj192993(v=azure.10).aspx

Now, we are devloping the setup program. And we want to automatize this procedure.
The installation of the Service "ServiceBus" is ok thanks to the scripts but now we have to generate the certificates from the server machine, copy them on the client machine and deploy these certificates.

My first question is : do we really need to have these certificats ? Because the application will work only on a local network.
If yes, my second question is : do you know a procedure to deploy automatically these certificats ?

Maybe, the first good thing should be to use our own certifcates and we should integrate in the setup program. But if it is possible, we should use these certifcats in the installation scripts of the "ServiceBus".

Thanks.

Comment: Im also intersted in this answer. Please post the answer if you have solved it

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to deploy the certificates - if you don't need mutual authentication:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415887/5869