# Periodical ServiceBus error "The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net is not in the trusted people store" when using Azure WebSites

Tags: .net, azure, servicebus

I have several websites running in Azure, intensively using ServiceBus (also hosted in Azure), all in one region.

Sometimes (once every 2-3 days) I have same error in all web sites at the same time (during reading/waiting for messages):

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: 
 The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net is not in the trusted people store.
  The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net chain building failed. 
   The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. 
    Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. 
     A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net is not in the trusted people store. The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
 ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net is not in the trusted people store. The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
 ---> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net is not in the trusted people store. The X.509 certificate CN=servicebus.windows.net chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.InitiateUpgradeAsyncResult.OnCompleteAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel`1.CreateChannelAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>d__7.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel`1.OnEndCreateInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager`1.EndGetInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__2(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass17.<GetAsyncSteps>b__a(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [2]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [3]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.CloseOrAbortLinkAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__7(CloseOrAbortLinkAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult a)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [4]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.AbandonPrefetchedMessagesCloseAbortAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__41(AbandonPrefetchedMessagesCloseAbortAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [5]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Olekstra.Common.QueueReader.<>c__DisplayClass3.<StartTask>b__2(Boolean force)
```

I'm using up-to-date version of `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` NuGet package (2.4.0.0), so answers from Google "certificate validation is off by default in ServiceBus 1.8" are useless - I had not turned any validation to ON, and moreover - it works many hours in a row and fails only once every 2-3 days.

Similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171931/azure-hosted-service-bus-the-x-509-certificate-cn-servicebus-windows-net-is-n) about self-hosted applications are not suitable too - website is running inside Azure, hosting VMs are manages by MS staff, I'm not allowed to update any root certificates.

Does anybody know why ServiceBus client decides to check SSL cert sometimes and how to disable this behaviour?

**UPD:**

I added `<add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.X509RevocationMode" value="NoCheck"/>` in `appSettings` in `web.config` two weeks ago - no difference.

Also Reflector shows that 'NoCheck' value is default in `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.GetCertificateRevocationMode()`

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

A change in Connectivity Mode *could* solve your problem.

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Https
```

It is normally `ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect`

According to a source in MS support

> "This will force all traffic to use a WebSockets tunnel that is
>   protected by a *prior* TLS/HTTPS handshake, and that handshake carries
>   the required intermediate certificate. The messaging protocol used
>   through that tunnel will still be AMQP or NetMessaging, so you should
>   not be worried to get HTTP characteristics when choosing this option."

So I figure that the certificate will only be fetched once in this scenario, and that may introduce an extra latency at that point, and then it is used forever after. It seems logical that the risk of getting your exception is thus reduced considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that **will** solve this problem but has security implications:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415887/5869

Comment: Unfortunately no. I can't create list of "trusted" certificates because all certificates are managed by MS/Azure and are changed/rotated without notification.